# How do you suppress matplotlib output in for loop in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am looping over a list of DataFrame column names to create barplots using matplotlib.pyplot in a Jupyter Notebook. Each iteration, I'm using the columns to group the bars. Like so:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


# Run all output interactively
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"


df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'col2': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 'col3': [10, 20, 30]})

#This DOES NOT suppress output
cols_to_plot = ['col1', 'col2']
for col in cols_to_plot:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.bar(df[col], df['col3'])
    plt.show();
```

The semicolon (';') should suppress text output but when I run the code I get, after the 1st run:

[image]

If I run a similar snippet outside of a `for` loop, it works as expected - the following successfully suppresses output:

```
# This DOES suppress output
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(df['col1'], df['col3'])
plt.show();
```

How do I suppress this text output when looping?

---

**Note:**

In a previous version of this question, I used the following code to which some of the comments refer, yet I changed it to the above to better show the issue.

```
cols_to_boxplot = ['country', 'province']
for col in cols_to_boxplot:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 10))
    sns.boxplot(y=wine['log_price'], x=wine[col])
    labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=90);
    ax.set_title('log_price vs {0}'.format(col))
    plt.show();
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. When running the above, there is no text output. But I guess you should use `sns.boxplot( ..., ax=ax)` to plot to the axes you create in the line above.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks for suggestion, but that didn't work. I wonder why you can't reproduce it. Maybe it's version-specific.

Comment: My suggestion has nothing to do with this issue, it's just in general that you should tell boxplot which axes to use if you created that axes beforehands - in this case it will not break anything if you don't do it, in other cases it would. Concerning the issue: Yes, post a [mcve], tell the versions you are using and best include a screenshot as well. For me, it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu0FZ.png).

Comment: I can also not reproduce this. I just get plots in the output in the same way as the screenshot in @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I edited my post as suggested but in doing so also answered my own question, which I also posted.

Comment: This last edit was not good. You should keep the question as question. A sentence about the problem on top, then the code to show the problem. I edited the question such that it will hopefully be useful for others.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I discovered what what causing this behaviour. I ran my notebook with the following:

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

([documented here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity))

This had the effect of not suppressing matplotlib output when plotting in a loop. However, as mentioned in the original post, it *did* suppress output as expected when *not* within a loop. In any case, I fixed the issue by 'undoing' my code above like this:

```
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "last_expr"
```

I'm not sure why this would happen.

Comment: Setting it to "none" helped resolve my error

Answer (score 0):

@voyager's answer worked for me, but only if I put

```
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "last_expr"
```

in the cell *preceding* the cell with the matplotlib annotate loop.

Alternative: I wrapped the plot code containing the annotate loop into a *plot function*.
If you call this function, the repeated 'Text' output remains *within* the function, no longer requiring a change to the InteractiveShell settings:

```
def plot_with_loop(df):
   ...
   ax = df.plot();

   for i in range(len(df)):
        # next line generates 'Text' output when not called contained in function
        ax.annotate(...); 
    

plot_with_loop(df)  # no 'Text' output
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `plt.show()` with `plt.close()`.

It worked for me.